# "A continuous competition" or "continuous competition"

Tags: nouns, articles, indefinite-articles, uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

I want to describe that school life is full of continuous competition, should I say "School life is continuous competition" or "Scool life is a continuous competition" ?

Answer (score 2):

You could use either.  The two meanings are subtly different but probably amount to the same thing in this instance.

I'll refer to this dictionary page:
http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/competition

1) *School life is continuous competition*

This is using defn 1: *"The activity or condition of striving to gain or win something by defeating or establishing superiority over others:"*

Ie, it's like saying "While we are at school we are continuously competing with others".

2) *School life is **a** continuous competition*

This is using defn 1.1: *"an event or contest in which people take part in order to establish superiority or supremacy in a particular area:"*

It's like saying "Being at school is like being in a competition".

So, the second one is a simile (you're not **actually** in a competition, even if it feels like it), while the first one is a more direct description.  Of course, school could be described as literally being a competition between students, especially if there are prizes, eg for best student in the year or whatever.  This makes the second one more literally true and less of a simile.

However, I think that most people would take the meaning to be the same in either case.